# How to add the `default-allow-http`

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform

How to add the `default-allow-http` firewall rule in a terraform script to a Google Cloud Compute Instance?

```
provider "google" {
    credentials = file("CREDENTIAL_FILE")
    project = "gitlab-project"
    region = var.region
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "gitlab" {
  name          = var.machine_specs.name
  machine_type  = var.machine_type.emicro
  zone          = var.zone

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
        image = var.machine_specs.os
        size = var.machine_specs.size
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    # A default network is created for all GCP projects
    network     = "default"
    access_config {
      nat_ip = google_compute_address.static.address
    }
  }

    // Add the SSH key
    metadata = {
        ssh-keys = "martin:${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")}"
    }

}

// A variable for extracting the external ip of the instance
output "ip" {
 value = "${google_compute_instance.gitlab.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip}"
}

resource "google_compute_address" "static" {
  name = "ipv4-address"
  address_type = "EXTERNAL"
  address = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "allow-http" {
  name = "default-allow-http"
  network = 

  allow{
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports = ["80"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider using this tool which builds terraform from existing environment ... you can see what you might need from there ... https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [tags](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance.html#tags) argument available in `google_compute_instance` resource.

it would look something like:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "gitlab" {
  name          = var.machine_specs.name
  machine_type  = var.machine_type.emicro
  zone          = var.zone

  tags = ["http-server"]
```

`http-server` tag is for `default-allow-http` firewall rule.
If you need `default-allow-https` then simply append `https-server` to the tag list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ran this and still didn't get the default-allow-http firewall rule... is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Can you share the output of "gcloud compute firewall-rules describe default-allow-http" ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the tags `["http-server", "https-server"]` to your resource group `google_compute_instance` like so:

```
[...]

resource "google_compute_instance" "gitlab" {
  name          = var.machine_specs.name
  machine_type  = var.machine_type.emicro
  zone          = var.zone

tags = ["http-server", "https-server"]

[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the tags `http-server` and `https-server` to your `google_cloud_instance` resource gruop. 
The tags can be found in the Firewall-settings in your GCloud-Console.